# Can I write go library to be used from another languages?

Tags: networking, dll, go, shared-libraries, portability

I'm writing relatively small, but not simple networking library which is going to be used at least from C,java,python,ruby and C#. Is there a way to make go bindings to the other languages the way in can be done form C? If not is there other way?

Comment: You should probably write the library in another language if you want it to be sharable with other languages. You can call `Go` from `C` (and some other languages), but it's not pretty and it's enough trouble that it would discourage me from using a library written Go from another language unless I had no other option. You can read about calling `Go` from `C` here: http://cheesesun.blogspot.com/2010/04/callbacks-in-cgo.html  You would face similar issues from C#. Java would be even more difficult, I believe. Not sure about Python.

Comment: You can't link to a `Go` library from another language. You can only call into `Go` from `C` within a Go program using `cgo`. Your program has to be running from the `Go` runtime.

Comment: @JimB what are other language choices besides C for such kind of project?

Comment: you have to go with the lowest common denominator which every language you want can make use of, which is this case is probably `C`, or maybe `C++`?

Comment: @JimB Can't I use dynamically or statically linked libraries with any other languages?

Comment: Yes you can, but only low level languages creates fitting APIs. Also there are initialisation issues. Potentially you could use C, C++ or D (I wrote such libraries with all of the above).

Comment: @kriss could you comment on your experience with D?

Comment: @kriss is using Rust also possible for this?

Comment: never tried with Rust, I will write an exemple with D (it actually needed some massaging, but more on the make side). But be aware I was not doing this on Windows but on Linux.

Comment: @kriss to be able to run well on linux is first priority for the project, with windows being the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you can't write libraries in Go that can be used in other languages. Go has a runtime environment that does a lot of things (like sheduling go-routines, collecting garbage) for you. This runtime environment is written under the assumption that it controls the whole program. This assumption does not hold if Go code would be used from inside another language, as the Go library cannot influence the binary that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that a JSON service would do what you describe. 
Have a look at [the json test](http://www.jsontest.com/) for a simple example
It wouldnt matter what languages you used to set and get data from your app